# List to Matrix using Hadoop

Tags: list, hadoop, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a list (in a tab-delimited .txt file) like:

```
row   col   value
1     1     3.2
10    2     5.3
25    3     2.2
30    1     5.3
```

etc.

And I want to turn it into a sparse matrix like:

```
    1    2    3
1   3.2  
10       5.3 
25            2.2
30  5.3
```

And then fill in the zeros.

What is the easiest way to do this with Hadoop? (I need to use Hadoop because the matrix will be about 3 Tb in size...)

Answer (score 1):

You could use either Hive or Pig. Here is an example of using Pig:

```
A = load 'input.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (row:long, col:int, value:float);
B = foreach a generate SOMEUDF(A);
store B into 'output.txt';
```

Then you just need to define a UDF:

```
public class SOMEUDF extends EvalFunc <Tuple>
{
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try{
            // Generate the matrix line here and return.
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
}
```